# Chaining the $http.get AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-get

As I am making few call to the endpoints within a function and it was causing issue with the parallel calls to the endpoints, so it was suggested in the other question to use the promise chaining. I updated my code so we can call the endpoints one after the other, so the code looks like below

```
 $scope.getRequest = function () {
        var url = $rootScope.BaseURL;
        var config = {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Basic ${$scope.key}`,
                'Prefer': 'odata.maxpagesize=2000'
            }
        };
        $http.get(url, config)
            .then(newViewRequest)
            .then(function(response){ 
                $scope.viewRequest.data = response.data;
            },
            function (response) { // failure async
                console.log("There was an error getting the request from CORE");});
   };

    var newViewRequest = function (response) {
        var url1 = $rootScope.BaseURL + `CMQ_REQUEST('${$scope.viewRequest.barcode}')`;
        if (response.data.REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST.length = 0) {
            return $http.get(url1, config)
         }
        return $q.reject({ message: 'Validations didnt work' });
    };
```

It always sends the reject message back from the newViewRequest if `response.data.REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST.length = 0`, if I comment it out I get the response.data is undefined.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your condition to validate instead of assigning

**Issue:** Update if condition as below to check response.data.REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST.length whether it is 0 or not with **===** instead of **=**

```
if (response.data.REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST.length === 0)
```

Comment: thank you but the issue is I dont get the response back with the $http.get call with in the If condition. I added the screenshot

Comment: @trx, try to console.log response1

Comment: The logs looks good. How can I get the response from the newViewRequest in to the $scope.viewRequest.data because response.data is undefined

Comment: please share the console.log for response1

Comment: Updated the screenshot

Comment: issue is you are returning $scope.viewRequest1.data and at line 30, you are accessinf response.data, as there is no data property it throws error , you can use simpley response or return $scope.viewRequest1 and use response.data

Comment: just for your reference add console.log for response as well at line 380